# Symfony: getting Class not found error

Tags: php, symfony, fatal-error

I am trying to learn Symfony 2. I'm trying to follow the example in the [Symfony book](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15538455/Symfony%202%20The%20Book%20.pdf) (Page 17). I have downloaded and unpacked Symfony in my working directory.

The absolute path to the file I'm trying to use is in: `symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request.php`

However following the books example closely, I just put:

`use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`

Either way, both these approaches did not work for me.

Using the books approach I'm getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request' not found in C:/...`

Using my approach with the longer path, I'm still getting this error, when I use `include` to navigate to the long path, the file is found but I'm getting some other error (just wanted to verify I'm able to get to the file, which I am).

I appreciate any advice in overcoming this problem. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in PHP `use` statement requires Fully Qualified Class Name, not directory. So `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` is just fine.

If you decided to try these "examples" you will have to require `autoload.php` file first. It is located in your **vendors** directory.

So if you make file named "myfile" in symfony `web` folder it should start like this:

```
<?php

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
```

Comment: +1, Thank you for the reply. How come Symfony doesn't load `autoload.php` in their example?

Comment: Well, those aren't really representative "examples". It's just introduction to the story. You will probably never write that code yourself because it's already written for you (see `app.php` and `app_dev.php` files in `web`) directory.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help... what would be a good way to study Symfony if not follow the examples closely?

Comment: Ugh....tough one. Probably varies on your experience in general programming, PHP, and understanding of MVC. When I started learning it I just read book a few times. One thing to keep in mind though is that it has pretty steep learning curve, but documentation is great so don't give up and it will all start to come together sooner or later.

Comment: I have a good understanding of general and OOP PHP but am new to frameworks and MVC.

Comment: You will have to figure it out yourself. It really depends on person, I don't think there's universal rule :) Just don't give up because it will be worth it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
Run - > composer update
Run the Path -> ./vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon
```

Then Will fixed this issue in laravel